# No Output for password checker with custom exception Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, custom-exceptions, password-checker

I am trying to make a program that checks a password from user input. The password criteria are that it has at least 10 characters, where at least 1 is a digit, 1 is a lower case and one is an upper case letter. For the assignment I have to create a custom exception class which is what is first below. I then have to create a method in a second class that checks each criteria and throws the exception with the proper error message. I have been trying for hours but for some reason my program will not print anything at all and I was hoping a fresh pair of eyes could help point me in the right direction. I am not looking for a handout, I just have a very weak grasp of custom exceptions (I have read the API, and my class book as well as gone to class everyday so its not that I'm not trying.)

```
public class PasswordException extends Exception {
    public PasswordException() {
    super("Invalid Password: ");

    }

    public PasswordException(String problem) {
    super("Invalid: " + problem );
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passwordMaker{

    public static boolean validPassword(String passwordIn) throws PasswordException {
        boolean lengthCheck = false;
        boolean upperCheck = false;
        boolean lowerCheck = false;
        boolean digitCheck = false;
        boolean check = false;
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        String problem;

        for(int i=0;i<passwordIn.length();i++) // This loop tests string
         {
             char s=passwordIn.charAt(i); // char s represents the index

           if(Character.isUpperCase(s)) // This verifies there is a uppercase letter
               {
               upperCheck = true;
               }
           if(Character.isLowerCase(s)) // This verifies there is a lowercase letter
               {
               lowerCheck=true;
               }
           if(Character.isDigit(s)) // This verifies there is a digit
               {
                digitCheck = true;
               }

           if (passwordIn.length() >= 10) // This verifies the password is atleast 6 characters
           {
           lengthCheck = true;
           }

         }

        do {
        //extracts problem 
        if (upperCheck == false) {
            problem  = "The password does not have an upper case letter.";
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        else if (lowerCheck == false) {
            problem = "The password does not have a lower case letter.";
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        else if (digitCheck == false) {
            problem = "The password does not have a digit.";
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        else if (lengthCheck == false) {
            problem = "The password is not long enough";
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        else {
            problem  = "nothing.";
            keepGoing = false;
        }
        }while(keepGoing);


          // Tests results of the loop
       if(upperCheck == true && lowerCheck == true && digitCheck == true && lengthCheck == true)
               {
               check=true;
               }

       if (check = true) {
           return true;
       }
       else {
           throw new PasswordException("the password needs" + problem);


       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a password.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String password = sc.next();

        try {
        validPassword(password);

    }
        catch (PasswordException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

}
}
```

I have tried running it through a visualizer but it will get to where I should input something and display a NoSuchElement error, while my command prompt does not, it simply wont display any messages after I input a password.

Comment: Are you allowed to use regex?

Comment: We havent learned about it yet so my professor doesnt want us to.

Comment: `if (check = true)` does not do what you think it does. Should be `if (check)`, or if you must be verbose `if (check == true)`. You should probably also be using `||` instead of `&&`, and you should be using a good IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enter a password.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String password = sc.next();

        try {
            validatePassword(password);
        } catch (PasswordException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static void validatePassword(String password) throws PasswordException {
        if (password.length() < 10) {
            throw new PasswordException("Password length is less than 10");
        }

        boolean upperCheck = false;
        boolean lowerCheck = false;
        boolean digitCheck = false;
        for (char c : password.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) // This verifies there is a uppercase letter
            {
                upperCheck = true;
            }

            if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) // This verifies there is a lowercase letter
            {
                 lowerCheck = true;
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) // This verifies there is a digit
            {
                  digitCheck = true;  
            }
        }

        if (!upperCheck) {
            throw new PasswordException("There must be an uppercase character");
        }

        if (!lowerCheck) {
            throw new PasswordException ("There must be a lowercase character");
        }

        if (!digitCheck) {
            throw new PasswordException ("There must a be a digit");
        }

        System.out.println("Valid password.");
    }

    static class PasswordException extends Exception {

        public PasswordException() {
            super("Invalid password");
        }

        public PasswordException(String message) {
            super("Invalid password: " + message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thank you, now let me compare to my code and see what i did wrong.